# Identify cell Column header name in On Row Data Bound Event

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I need to Display Description of the cell using tool tip.I need to identify the header of the cell using OnRowDataBound.

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdOne" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="common_tbl full_width" AllowPaging="true" 
 OnPageIndexChanging="grdOne_PageIndexChanging" OnRowDataBound="grdOne_OnRowDataBound">

<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Bank Code">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblBankCode" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("BankCode")%>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Branch Code">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblBranchCode" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("BranchCode")%>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>

protected void grdOne_OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
}
```

Comment: where do you want to show tool tip?

Comment: When mouse pointer is on a cell

Answer (score 2):

Hope this will work

```
protected void grdOne_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        e.Row.ToolTip = "Description";
    }
 }
```

or

```
protected void grdOne_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
             e.Row.Attributes.Add("title", "Description");
        }
     }
```